# Android Studio - no exception stack trace

Tags: android, android-studio

I have the newest canary Android Studio installed (but the problem occurred also on the latest stable version). When I run a project and when at some point it gets to

```
Someobject object = null;
object.doSomething();
```

code, The android studio logcat should write a stack trace of uncaught exception. But logcat is not displaying that. It's frustrating because in project it really takes a long time to find the error without the stack trace.

This is what my logcat says: http://pastebin.com/mQbbpBy0

This is what I expect it to say: http://pastebin.com/Yu83dwNg

I have tried to reinstall android studio. I deleted and downloaded SDK again but no success.I also searched for some solution on the internet but no help. I don't know what other info would be helpful for you. I gladly give you any info you need. Thank you.

Comment: What is logcat displaying then? Nothing? Does it display normally when you Log.d things?

Comment: Don't think I can help then. Im guessing you already tried everything that's on the net like `adb kill-server` and `adb start-server` or redownloading AVD.

Comment: Yes, all that tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have enough rep to post a comment, otherwise I'd put it there -- are you running this on a real device or on an emulator?

If a real device:  The error "libmaliinstr.so not found" can occur in specific phones which are missing that library -- you could try an emulator, e.g. Nexus 5, if this is the case.

Comment: So what is the solution?